# Integrals of a general function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

While reviewing an old calculus book the following were asked:

> Let $v$ denote $e^{i x}$ then if $f$ denote any function, $|c| \leq 1$,
>   \begin{align}
> I_{1} &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{f(a + v) + f(a + v^{-1})}{1 - 2 c \, \cos x + c^{2}} \, dx = \frac{2 \pi}{1 - c^{2}} \, f(a + c) \\
> I_{2} &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{f(a+v) + f(a + v^{-1})}{1 - 2 c \, \cos x + c^{2}} \, \sin x \, dx = \frac{i \pi }{c} \left( f(a+c) - f(a) \right) \\
> I_{3} &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1 - c \, \cos x}{1 - 2c \, \cos x + c^{2}} \, \left( f(a + v) + f(a + v^{-1}) \right) \, dx = \pi \left( f(a+c) + f(a) \right)
> \end{align}

What are some methods to demonstrate the integral identities are true ?

Comment: May be we should use residues?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza The use of residues would be an interesting method.

Comment: There's certainly no hope without the assumption that $f$ is analytic.